# how to keep all methods in a class with ProGuard

Tags: android, proguard

I use ProGuard to optimize my Android Application. However for Android instrumentation test I need some (but not all) classes to keep all there members. I tried various approaches, the last being:

```
-keepclassmembers public class com.mycompany.myclass {
    *;
}
```

But surprisingly I still get

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mycompany.myclass.<init>
```

The painful part here is that there are two constructors and one has quite a few parameters.

Does anyone know the correct syntax to keep a class completely unchanged and untouched by ProGuard?

Comment: Use the `<methods>` wildcard.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, it is confession time. The question is bollocks. The `-keepclassmembers` is correct. The problem occurred because a team mate broke the code and the constructor was truly not there.

Note that if there is a change that the whole class is optimized away then you should use `-keep` as kharles suggested but the `{*;}` is needed to ensure that all methods stay in place.

Note that the `{*;}` is for testing only. For production one should use a more fine grained approach.

I keep the question for anybody with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
-keep public class com.mycompany.myclass
```

( use keep, and no {*;} )

Comment: No, that makes it worse. The embarrassing truth: My statements above are correct — A team mate broke the code and this is why it did not work.

So delete the question or keep of for others with the same problem?